# Return resultset from oracle 11g stored procedure using classic asp

Tags: stored-procedures, asp-classic, oracle11g

We recently upgraded from Oracle 10g to 11g and now the microsoft provider `MSDAORA.1` won't work. I've changed to using the `OraOLEDB.Oracle` provider but now one of my stored procedures that is returning a resultset isn't going to work either.

**Old Call:**
    strSQL = "{call SYSADM.lss_pkg_catalog_pages.get_catalog_pages(?,{resultset 100, lss_media_cd, lss_page_num})}"

So I've been trying to change it to return parameter values but I keep getting the following error: `Error: -2147217900 - ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_CATALOG_XXX' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_CATALOG_XXX' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored`

I'm guessing that it's because of the data type of my output parameters but can't seem to find the right type to use.

**Here is the code I'm using:**

```
dim con, rst1, prm1, prm2, prm3, prm4

set cmCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Rst1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Con.Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
Con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=XXXXXX;Password=XXXXXX;User ID=XXXXX;Persist Security Info=True"
Con.Open

cmCmd.ActiveConnection = Con
cmCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

Set Prm1 = cmCmd.CreateParameter("PRODUCT_ID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, strTempProductID)
cmCmd.Parameters.Append Prm1                                

Set Prm2 = cmCmd.CreateParameter("LSS_MEDIA_XX", adVarWChar, adParamOutput, 100) 
cmCmd.Parameters.Append Prm2                

Set Prm3 = cmCmd.CreateParameter("LSS_PAGE_XXX", adVarWChar, adParamOutput, 100) 
cmCmd.Parameters.Append Prm3 

strSql = "{ CALL SYSADM.lss_pkg_catalog_pages.get_catalog_pages(?, ?, ?) }" 

cmCmd.CommandText = strSql
cmCmd.Execute
```

I have other straight SQL and other stored procedure calls that return data just fine it's just this one stored procedure that isn't working properly.

**Edit:**
I was asked about the type declaration inside the Oracle stored procedure:

```
TYPE t_lss_media_XXX is TABLE of ps_lss_cat_XXXX.lss_XXX%TYPE
          INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

TYPE t_lss_page_XXX is TABLE of ps_lss_cat_XXXX.lss_XXXX%TYPE
           INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

If there is more information necessary from the store procedure let me know and I can post it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Robert

Comment: Pls check this link from OTN :[Stored Procedures and Functions Returning Rowsets](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e17726/using.htm#autoId23)

Comment: I looked at that site and specifically the section on `PLSQLRSet` and even copied the code and modified it for my situation and still get the same error.

Comment: can you show the modified code ? you could edit your question .

Comment: .. And, as that link shows, can you change the types of those two to ref_cursors ?

Comment: The code sample is the code I'm using which was copied from that site and modified to meet my needs.

Comment: I tried changing to RefCursor as the datatype for both output parameters and now get the following error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Comment: @SearchAndResQ changing the procedure to return ref cursors did it.  Please answer the question and I'll give you proper credit.

Comment: It's ok, Please post your solution and mark as answer for future reference.I didn't do much except search :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a suggestion by @searchAnResQ in the comments I had our oracle team redo the stored procedure to return a Ref Cursor and that seemed to do the trick.  I found that returning a table wasn't supported by the ODAC version we were working with.