# Classic ASP/OraOLEDB - how to define OUT param containing TABLE?

Tags: stored-procedures, asp-classic, oracle11g, oledb, oraoledb

A classic ASP script migrated from msdaora to OraOLEDB will no long execute an Oracle SP it used to.

The SP looks like this :

```sql
TYPE tbl_CONSOLIDATED_ID      IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE tblSAM_DD_TEXT     IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE tblSAM_TYPE     IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
--
PROCEDURE Get_Associated_Samples(
EMPID_IN IN MAS_EMPLOYEE.EMP_AUTOID%TYPE,
ID_OUT OUT tbl_CONSOLIDATED_ID,
SAMDDTEXT_OUT OUT tblSAM_DD_TEXT,
SAMTYPE_OUT OUT tblSAM_TYPE
);
```

And the ASP to invoke it looks like this :

```vb
Const cProcName = "{call VERIFICATION_SUPPORT.Get_Associated_Samples(?,{resultset 100, ID_OUT, SAMDDTEXT_OUT, SAMTYPE_OUT})}"   

Set MASconnLocal = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strCNLocalPath = ORAOLEDBCONNECTIONSTRING 
MASconnLocal.Open(strCNLocalPath)

Set cmdStoredProc = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Set cmdStoredProc.ActiveConnection = MASconnLocal

cmdStoredProc.CommandText = cProcName 
cmdStoredProc.CommandType = 1 

Set paramEMPID = cmdStoredProc.CreateParameter ("EMPID_IN", adInteger, adParamInput)

paramEMPID.Value = strEMPID

cmdStoredProc.Parameters.Append paramEMPID

Set rs = cmdStoredProc.Execute
```

The error reported in the IIS log is :

```
ORA-06550:_line_1__column_54:_PLS-00201:_identifier_'ID_OUT'_must_be_declared_ORA-06550
```

What to do ?

From my reading so far I've read suggestions that I should, within the ASP, define parameters for each of the output parameters in the same way that I have for paramEMPID, something like this :

```vb
dim paramIDOut 
dim paramSamDDTextOut
dim paramSamTypeOut

set paramIDOut = cmdStoredProc.CreateParameter ("ID_OUT" ) 
set paramSamDDTextOut = cmdStoredProc.CreateParameter ("SAMDDTEXT_OUT")
set paramSamTypeOut = cmdStoredProc.CreateParameter ("SAMTYPE_OUT")

cmdStoredProc.Parameters.Append paramIDOut
cmdStoredProc.Parameters.Append paramSamDDTextOut
cmdStoredProc.Parameters.Append paramSamTypeOut
```

However to do a 'CreateParameter' requires more arguments than I have shown there and I don't know what argument values are suitable when the SP Parameter being referred to is, for instance, a 'TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50).

I do appreciate the contemporary way of doing this is to return a ref cursor but the application is old and not long for the world, I would much prefer to change as little as possible.

Comment: I'm no expect on Oracle but I'm pretty sure you can't return a `TABLE OF` type like that, you have to use a cursor type - see [How To Retrieve Recordsets from Oracle Stored Procedures Using ADO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176086/EN-US).

Comment: @Lankymart thanks for your comment but this was working when the msdaora driver was in use so . BTW it appears you have made an edit to my question - what have you changed ?

Comment: SO uses a wiki format, if you click on the edit link next to my name it will take you to the questions edit history. I used markdown syntax to add appropriate syntax highlighting to your code blocks nothing more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return resultset from oracle 11g stored procedure using classic asp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494938/return-resultset-from-oracle-11g-stored-procedure-using-classic-asp)